# How to edit or add video metadata of "rotation" in mp4?

Tags: multimedia

I want put rotation information into my mp4 video file but I have no idea about this.

Is there any program that I can add "rotation" metadata?
It would be OK if there's the way to edit video content with hexa editor.

Answer (score 22):

+1 for FFMpeg. More specifically, I had good results [*correcting* orientation metadata](http://thornelabs.net/2013/06/04/correct-smartphone-video-orientation-and-how-to-rotate-ios-and-android-videos-with-ffmpeg.html) with

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -metadata:s:v rotate=90 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Does this still work?  I have FFmpeg version 3.2.4 on a Mac with Brew, and rotate 0, 1, 2, and 3 are all not transforming the resultant video file at all.  Side note, I have recorded my video files with a video camera, and they appear fine in VLC.  I reduce the bitrate to a custom value. and optimize for web in Handbrake, then for the resultant video I can only hear audio, and in Mac's Quick Look feature in Finder, it is rotated 180 degrees.

Comment: Will this re-encode the video? I just want to set the rotation meta data, no re-encoding.

Comment: @csabaToth yes this just re-muxes, no re-encoding (see the `copy` codecs).

Comment: @pysis - I just re-tested and it works fine here, but you'll need to do 0, 90, 180, 270 not 0,1,2,3 it seems. Your player has to support that metadata of course - if not you'll have to physically transpose the video (ffmpeg can do this too) and re-encode

Answer (score 1):

Check out the software [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), use ffprobe to give you the rotation metadata of any video file if it has it.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408542/video-captured-from-iphone-gets-rotated-when-converted-to-mp4-using-ffmpeg/9409094#9409094) for functions allowing your to rotate videos.

Answer (score 0):

See my [more in depth answer to same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77923968/1437625)

In summary:

`exiftool -Rotation=90 your_file.mp4`

Set the value to whatever you need. Eg, if you are removing unwanted rotation, set to 0.

More info on the fantastic `exiftool` can be found here: https://exiftool.org