# How to rotate mp4 files?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, rotation, mp4

I have a mp4 file(already recorded) and want to change the rotation(including meta data) of the video. There is a way to do this using [Hex Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) where in you find the track header(tkhdr) and replace the rotation matrix with the required rotation.

I know this can be done using ffmpeg library but I do not want to use the library instead I want to do this in Android using JAVA. Let me know if anyone has done this before.

Thanks
Ravi

[Reference link](https://superuser.com/questions/1307158/change-rotation-flag-in-mp4-video-without-losing-metadata)

Answer (score 3):

This library may help you: https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android

This library generates an Mp4 movie using Android MediaCodec API and can rotate Mp4.

StackOverflow reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19392712/8572503

---

It's API is fluent and easy :

```
new Mp4Composer(sourceFile, destinationFile) 
            .rotation(Rotation.ROTATION_90)
            .size(1280,720) //720P
            .fillMode(FillMode.PRESERVE_ASPECT_FIT)
            .listener(new Mp4Composer.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(double progress) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgress = " + progress);
                    //or show in notification
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.v(TAG, "onCompleted() : Destination → "+ destinationFile);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCanceled() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCanceled");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailed(Exception exception) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "onFailed()", exception);
                }
            })
            .start();
```

---

You can also see this transcoder has written in pure Java: https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder

---

**[EDIT: From Comment]**:

You can extract code from this: https://github.com/javadev/hexeditor to manually modify the hex.

Comment: add few code example so anyone can easily understand about that library rather directly go to link @Toaster

Comment: Thanks @Toaster for your reply. I think this will create a new file rather than doing the changes in the same file.

Comment: My idea is to get byte array from the file,  search the rotation property in that byte array and change the rotation. The problem with this approach is that I am unable to find the rotation matrix from the byte array.

Comment: I can't say that anything won't work. But does android support real-time file modifications? I haven't tried to try it yet.

Comment: @Toaster Thank you. I will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Did you try @ravi ?

Comment: @Toaster I think this library will re-encode the entire file  instead of just changing the rotation matrix. Moreover this might take considerable amount of time if the size of MP4 file is 3-4 GB.