# Mirror Video in android using mp4Parser?

Tags: android, mp4parser

How can I create the mirrored value of a video using mp4Parser.
If it is possible what value for matrix will work.
Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is:

```
-1  0  0 
 0  1  0
 0  0  1
```

This code sets the matrix to the first track in the file:

```
    IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile("input.mp4");
    TrackHeaderBox tkhd = 
           (TrackHeaderBox) Path.getPath(isoFile, "/moov[0]/trak[0]/tkhd[0]");
    tkhd.setMatrix(new Matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0));
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.mp4");
    isoFile.getBox(fos.getChannel());
```

But be aware that not all players support matrix tranformations.

Have a look here to see [how to make VideoView respect the matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177912/mp4parser-change-video-orientation/17395134#17395134)
.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for providing us with this great library. I tried the above code with android and made video preview in android VideoView, it seems that video doesn't show any change.

Comment: Video rotation using Matrix.ROTATE_270 and Matrix.ROTATE_90 is working fine with me.

Comment: Please try it with quicktime if you can. My test with quicktime worked (vlc didn't)

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I need the videos to be played in android VideoView. Am using library in android application. Any other alternative?

Comment: I didn't mean to use quicktime completely. I just suggested to use quicktime - as its known to support the matrix settings - to verify that the file was written correctly.

Comment: Another chance for you might setting the matrix at the Movie Header Box (/moov/mvhd) - perhaps VideoView respects it there.

Comment: Hi Mahesh,
would you please vote up for my answer? My matrix mirrors the video, unfortunately your VideoView doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble getting the matrix right for rotating 90 and then flipping horizontally. What would that matrix constructor look like? I find it a bit confusing that the matrix order differs so from android.graphics.matrix.